# NVARCHAR (MAX) in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, maxlength

I am creating a table in Sqlite with a column with max length:

```
create table [Log] (
    Id int identity not null
        constraint PK_Log_Id primary key,
    Data nvarchar (max) null
)
```

But the following line is not being accepted:

```
Data nvarchar (max) null
```

Why?

Answer (score 18):

`max` is specific to SQL Server (and I think Sybase).  Just use `text`:

```
data text not null
```

or, you can really use any character string data type.  SQLite doesn't enforce length restrictions:

> Note that numeric arguments in parentheses that following the type
>   name (ex: "VARCHAR(255)") are ignored by SQLite - SQLite does not
>   impose any length restrictions (other than the large global
>   SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH limit) on the length of strings, BLOBs or numeric
>   values.

(see [here](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)).