# base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); preventing other code from executing

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

My code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebApplication4.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>(entity =>
            {
                                entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnType("text");
            entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnType("text");
            entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedName).HasColumnType("text");
            entity.Property(e => e.ConcurrencyStamp).HasColumnType("text");
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Error thrown:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE "AspNetRoles" (
    "Id" nvarchar(450) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_AspNetRoles" PRIMARY KEY,
    "Name" nvarchar(256) NULL,
    "NormalizedName" nvarchar(256) NULL,
    "ConcurrencyStamp" nvarchar(max) NULL
);
```

More code relevant to the issue:

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
     options.UseSqlite(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=mydb.db"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I have not managed to find a solution.

Comment: Move `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` outside of the `modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>(entity =>` function so it is the last line of the `OnModelCreating` method.

Comment: could you please provide me with a code example of what you are suggesting?

edit: okay, I gave it a try with no success.

Comment: Is there anything else in the error message like the failure message reason

Comment: Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'near "max": syntax error'.

Comment: There is not type max in SQL

Comment: My question has been edited to reflect the changes in my code. With the changes, I get the following error: Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE "AspNetRoles" (
    "Id" nvarchar(450) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_AspNetRoles" PRIMARY KEY,
    "Name" nvarchar(256) NULL,
    "NormalizedName" nvarchar(256) NULL,
    "ConcurrencyStamp" nvarchar(max) NULL
);

SQLite Error 1: 'near "max": syntax error'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44145096/nvarchar-max-in-sqlite

Comment: It looks like you haven't installed package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite. Also you need to tell entity framework to use Sqlite   protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={DbPath}");

Comment: The package is installed. Where exactly would I put that code?

Comment: where do you set your connection string?

Comment: appsettings.json.

Comment: In the code where do you set it. I assume during the DI.

Comment: I edited my question to provide clarity.

Comment: Try suggestion provided here to delete migrations folder https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/865